# Using a variable as a Map key MongoDB Groovy Query

Tags: mongodb, groovy

I've a mongo db query to fetch some data as shown below

```
collection.find(lastUpdated: ['$gte': startDate.toLong(), '$lt': endDate.toLong()], resource: ['$gt': limit]).findAll().toList()
```

`resource` is a dynamic field which could have values like:
`parameter1`, `parameter2` ... and so on.

I'm passing `resource` as method parameter in this query.

Can somebody suggest some way through which I can dynamically use `resource` without hard coding its value as (`paramter1` or `parameter2` or `parameter3` ...) in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah you are almost there you just need to pass it as a variable and use `()` syntax on the `Map` to indicate that you are using a variable as a key instead of a literal value.

change this:

```
resource: ['$gt': limit]
```

to this:

```
(resource): ['$gt': limit]
```

---

Full query:

```
def resource = "parameter1"; //or parameter2 ...
collection.find(lastUpdated: ['$gte': startDate.toLong(), '$lt': endDate.toLong()], (resource): ['$gt': limit]).findAll().toList()
```

Comment: you welcome; it happens when working with a new language ;)